# EnumProcessModules fails with ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE from inside process

Tags: winapi, pinvoke

I want to enumerate all the modules inside my own process - both native and managed. So I wrapped EnumProcessModules with the following P/Invoke declaration:

```
[DllImport("psapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool EnumProcessModules(
        IntPtr hProcess,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.SysInt)]
        [In][Out] IntPtr[] lphModule,
        uint cb,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        out uint lpcbNeeded);
```

And I call it from my own process (close to its start time) using

```
var processHandle = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle;
uint needed;
EnumProcessModules(processHandle, new IntPtr[0], 0, out needed);
var modules = new IntPtr[needed * 2];
bool enumResult = EnumProcessModules(processHandle, modules, (uint)(needed * IntPtr.Size), out needed);
```

In the production environment, most of the time this works but from time to time the second call fails and the last error code is 6 which is `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`. I know from reading online and from looking at the [reference .NET implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/ProcessManager.cs,65bb77baa7d77923) that sometimes this function fails if OS loader is touching the module information, but then I think that the error should be `ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY`. I don't understand how I can get `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE` when running from my own process.

I tried to recreate this in a test by running the code in a loop (hoping at some random iteration it would fail) but the problem didn't reproduce. The interesting (and weird) thing about this is that I manage to recreate this in the following manner:

- Add a breakpoint somewhere in the code
- Debug the test
- Hit the breakpoint
- Remove the breakpoint
- Continue debugging (F5)
- Then the error occurs

These reproduction steps worked several times in a row. The error occurred each time after I continued debugging. I also saw in the reference code that `EnumProcessModules` is called in a loop in case it fails. I tried to do the same but it doesn't help. Once the error occurs, it occurs for at least 50 more times...

The code is x86 running on a x64 machine.

Comment: Quote it properly: "with a strange error **like** ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY.".  Given that you know it *can* fail, you must of course deal with the possibility that it *will* fail.

Comment: Yes, of course, but some errors shouldn't happen in different scenarios (e.g. Can't get FileNotFound if file is there). So I don't understand how it's possible that I get InvalidHandle, and what I can do to make sure that it doesn't happen. With the case the OS loader is just doing something I can deal with by calling the function again. But with an invalid handle I'm not sure what I can do.

Comment: The only thing you *can* do, for any error, sleep for a bit and try again.

Comment: I tried doing the same as the reference source - Thread.Sleep(1) and repeat 50 times. But it didn't help. I can try to sleep a longer time.

Comment: You also need to disable anti-malware to make sure it doesn't mess things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so the problem is that the `Handle` which is returned from Process is not safe to use and gets collected. Here's a little repro I wrote

```
var handle = new IntPtr(-1); // works
var handle = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle; // doesn't work

GC.Collect();

uint needed;
var modules = new IntPtr[1024];

var enumResult = ModulesCheck.EnumProcessModules(handle, modules, (uint)modules.Length, out needed);
Console.WriteLine(enumResult);
```

So I guess I should either use -1 or get a `SafeWaitHandle` and keep it alive until I'm done with the enumerations.

P.S. For the repro to work - must run it in Release mode!